# Integrating Dropwizard with Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, dropwizard

I have found Dropwizard to be amazing framework to quickly build REST services and most of my enterprise conserns are taken care by this f/w except one. It does provide mechanism to secure you service but it is not as extensive as Spring Security.

I want to understand how these two can marry and whether gluing them together is right or not. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11):

I have been able to successfully integrate Spring Security with Dropwizard in the project I just finished. Spring Security is really just a glorified ServletFilter that you can add to the Dropwizard application.

Jacek Furmankiewicz has a small sample project that integrates Spring with Dropwizard and this is the specific part regarding how to add the Spring Security filter to the DW app.

https://github.com/jacek99/dropwizard-spring-di-security-onejar-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/jacek99/myapp/MyAppService.java

One thing to keep in mind with the example provided is that this is for Dropwizard 0.6.2 and the current recommended release is 0.7.0.

So instead of this (0.6.2):

```
environment.addFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.class,"/*").setName("springSecurityFilterChain");
```

use this:

```
FilterRegistration.Dynamic filterRegistration = environment.servlets().addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
filterRegistration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), false, "/*");
```

-Matt